# How to give a condition that if difference between two hexadecimal no is 2 then concatenate two rows?

Tags: python

I have a file which contain two columns, eg
`abc.txt`

```
000000008b8c5200        af dg sd jh g1 43 66 23 67
000000008b8c5220        bc bi ub cb ue qi hd 16 72
0000000056fb2620        ad ag sj ha bn bc bh 53 69
0000000056fb2640        ak bh jg bf re 34 16 8g ff
0000000045ab4630        sg fj g3 6g dh w7 28 g7 dg
0000000045ab4650        jb sh jd b7 us vy ys du 89
```

Here I need to concatenate 2nd row 2nd column with first row first column like this:

```
bcbiubcbueqihd1672afdgsdjhg143662367
```

Condition for concatenating:
only when (hexadecimal)difference between 2nd row, 1st column and 1st row, 1st column is 20. For this example it would be:

```
000000008b8c5220 - 000000008b8c5200 = 20.
0000000056fb2640 - 0000000056fb2620 = 20.
0000000045ab4650 - 0000000045ab4630 = 20.
```

Similarly for upcoming rows and columns. Write the results to a file with first row and concatenated data like this:

```
000000008b8c5200 bcbiubcbueqihd1672afdgsdjhg143662367
0000000056fb2620 akbhjgbfre34168gffadagsjhabnbcbh5369
0000000045ab4630 jbshjdb7usvyysdu89sgfjg36gdhw728g7dg
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please add the complete desired output of the file for the provided example? It is not clear to me how you want to treat the "upcoming rows and columns".

Comment: ok, just to be clear, the hecadecimal difference of all these rows is not equal to 20. It seems you build the difference of the last to digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as g:
    out = []
    lines = [elem.strip().split() for elem in f] # lines will be list of lists, each list with 2 elements (-> 2 columns)
    for line_x, line_y in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]): # use zip and steps of 2 to iterate like: 1&2, 3&4, 5&6...
        num_x = int(line_x[0], base=16) # convert hex to int
        num_y = int(line_y[0], base=16)
        print(num_x, num_y, num_y - num_x)
        if num_y - num_x == 32:
            # if difference is 20, build string seperated by tab with the hex number and the concatenated data
            new_row = '\t'.join([line_x[0], line_y[1] + line_y[1]])
            out.append(new_row)
    g.write('\n'.join(out)) # write all new rows to output file
```

For the provided example it prints:

```
2341229056 2341229088 32
1459299872 1459299904 32
1168852528 1168852560 32
```

Because no row difference is 20 there will be no data in the output file.

**UPDATE**
for your changed input you can do it like this:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as g:
    out = []
    lines = [elem.strip().split() for elem in f] # lines will be list of lists
    print(lines[0]) # this is how each line looks
    # ['000000008b8c5200', 'af', 'dg', 'sd', 'jh', 'g1', '43', '66', '23', '67']
    
    for a, b in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]): # use zip and steps of 2 to iterate like: 1&2, 3&4, 5&6...
        num_a, remaining_a = a[0], ''.join(a[1:])
        num_b, remaining_b = b[0], ''.join(b[1:])
        
        if int(num_b, base=16) - int(num_a, base=16) == 20: # convert hex string to int and build difference
            # if difference is 20, build a tuple with the number as 1st element and concatenated data as 2nd element
            new_row = '\t'.join([num_a, remaining_b + remaining_a])
            out.append(new_row)
            
    g.write('\n'.join(out)) # write row to new file
```

Comment: this code is working. Thank You!

Comment: but what if datas are seperated by space like what is given in above table. I tried to replace the space with "" but it's not working.

Comment: this will change the data because `line_x[1]` will be just the next element (of 2 letters) instead of the remaining data in that row. I will have a look and update my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question is how to make hex str to int (for the subtraction)

you can use the `int` command with 2nd parameter as the base (16)

```
>>> int('abc', 16)
2748
>>> int('000000008b8c5220',16) - int('000000008b8c5200',16) == 0x20
True
```

if your qustion is how to read the text from the file:

```py
with open('filename.txt') as my_file:
    file_data = [line.replace('\n','').split('        ') for line in my_file if line]
```

and now you have a 2D array of strs of your data